# Enabling i2c1 on beaglebone black using dtb

Tags: linux-device-driver, beagleboneblack, device-tree

I have enabled I2C bus 2 on beagle bone black using the following lines in the dtb

```
i2c2: i2c@4819c000 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&i2c2_pins>;
    status = "okay";
    clock-frequency = <100000>;
};    

i2c2_pins: pinmux_i2c2_pins {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <
        0x178 0x73  
        0x17c 0x73
    >;
};
```

But when I the same to enable the I2C bus 1 using the code below

```
i2c1: i2c@4802a000 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&i2c1_pins>;
    status = "okay";
    clock-frequency = <100000>;
};

i2c1_pins: pinmux_i2c1_pins {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <
        0x154 0x72  /* i2c1_scl.i2c1_scl */
        0x15c 0x72  /* i2c1_sda.i2c1_sda */
    >;
};
```

The bus get listed in the `i2cdetect -l` command. But probing the bus using the `i2cdetect -r 1` command gives me the following error

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          [   18.322700] omap_i2c 4802a000.i2c: timeout waiting for bus ready
-- [   19.342694] omap_i2c 4802a000.i2c: timeout waiting for bus ready
-- [   20.362695] omap_i2c 4802a000.i2c: timeout waiting for bus ready
```

I am using the ZCZ package of AM3359 chip. Could any one point me the mistake i make in the dtb file?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved I enabled the wrong line. Refering the wrong datasheet. It should be

```
+               i2c1_pins: pinmux_i2c1_pins {
+                       pinctrl-single,pins = <
+                               0x158 0x72      /* uart1_ctsn.i2c2_sda, SLEWCTRL_SLOW | INPUT_PULLUP | MODE2 */
+                               0x15c 0x72      /* uart1_rtsn.i2c2_scl, SLEWCTRL_SLOW | INPUT_PULLUP | MODE2 */
+                       >;
+               };
```

Comment: Hi @Prajosh are you able to post your full device tree overlay .dts code please? I'm having trouble trying to enable I2C1 on pins 24 & 26. Currently I'm using this device tree [here at github](https://github.com/beagleboard/devicetree-source/blob/master/arch/arm/boot/dts/BB-I2C1A1-00A0.dts). When using i2cdetect for my StrongLink SL030 RFID, address 0x50 is blank.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but can you explain a bit more about what a "dtb" is, and what file exactly you are editing?

Answer (score 0):

@RobHurd

I have used the files found at this place https://git.ti.com/ti-linux-kernel/ti-linux-kernel/trees/ti-linux-3.12.y/arch/arm/boot/dts

Please find the patch I added

```
diff --git a/arch/arm/boot/dts/am335x-bone-common.dtsi b/arch/arm/boot/dts/am335x-bone-common.dtsi
index a0efb06..835c973 100644
--- a/arch/arm/boot/dts/am335x-bone-common.dtsi
+++ b/arch/arm/boot/dts/am335x-bone-common.dtsi
@@ -31,6 +31,7 @@
                0x58 (PIN_OUTPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE7)    /* gpmc_a6.gpio1_22 */
                0x5c (PIN_OUTPUT_PULLDOWN | MUX_MODE7)  /* gpmc_a7.gpio1_23 */
                0x60 (PIN_OUTPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE7)    /* gpmc_a8.gpio1_24 */
+               0x164 (PIN_OUTPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE7)
            >;
        };

@@ -41,6 +42,20 @@
            >;
        };

+       i2c1_pins: pinmux_i2c1_pins {
+           pinctrl-single,pins = <
+               0x158 0x72      /* uart1_ctsn.i2c2_sda, SLEWCTRL_SLOW | INPUT_PULLUP | MODE2 */
+                                0x15c 0x72      /* uart1_rtsn.i2c2_scl, SLEWCTRL_SLOW | INPUT_PULLUP | MODE2 */
+           >;
+       };
+
+       i2c2_pins: pinmux_i2c2_pins {
+           pinctrl-single,pins = <
+               0x178 0x73  /* uart1_ctsn.i2c2_sda, SLEWCTRL_SLOW | INPUT_PULLUP | MODE3 */
+               0x17c 0x73  /* uart1_rtsn.i2c2_scl, SLEWCTRL_SLOW | INPUT_PULLUP | MODE3 */
+           >;
+       };
+
        uart0_pins: pinmux_uart0_pins {
            pinctrl-single,pins = <
                0x170 (PIN_INPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE0)    /* uart0_rxd.uart0_rxd */

@@ -202,6 +223,20 @@
            };

        };
+
+       i2c1: i2c@4802a000 {
+           pinctrl-names = "default";
+           pinctrl-0 = <&i2c1_pins>;
+           status = "okay";
+           clock-frequency = <400000>;
+       };
+
+       i2c2: i2c@4819c000 {
+           pinctrl-names = "default";
+           pinctrl-0 = <&i2c2_pins>;
+           status = "okay";
+           clock-frequency = <400000>;
+       };
    };
diff --git a/arch/arm/boot/dts/am335x-boneblack.dts b/arch/arm/boot/dts/am335x-boneblack.dts
index 2f64afa..0954ac1 100644
--- a/arch/arm/boot/dts/am335x-boneblack.dts
+++ b/arch/arm/boot/dts/am335x-boneblack.dts
@@ -69,6 +69,15 @@
    };
 };

+&i2c2 {
+   touchcontroller: atmel_maxtouch@4b  {
+       compatible = "atmel,maxtouch";
+       reg = <0x4b>;
+       interrupt-parent = <&gpio2>;
+       interrupts = <1 8>; // gpio2[1] 8
+   };
+};
+
 &lcdc {
    pinctrl-names = "default", "off";
    pinctrl-0 = <&nxp_hdmi_bonelt_pins>;
```

Answer (score -1):

The following command will enable i2c1 on beaglebone black. (Kernel 3.8 -- newer kernels do not support `bone_capemgr.*` *yet*)

```
echo BB-I2C1 > /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.8/slots
```

Note: Pull down is enabled.

**Reference**

- [BeagleBone Black I2C References](http://datko.net/2013/11/03/bbb_i2c/)

Comment: I need to have the i2c bus on startup as my touch chip is connected on this bus. So I need to enable it over dtb

Comment: This does appear to enable I2C1 as I2C2. However, when using i2cdetect it does not recognise my SL030 RFID reader at address 0x50. I'm using pins 24 & 26.